# jQuery Background-Color change with fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

It's my first post here and my English ... Yeah...

I want to change my background-color with a fadeIn/Out - I think so - when I do a mouseover over my '#bg2'.

This is the code I use:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#bg1').mouseover(function(){
      $('body').css('background', '#361738')
   });
   $('#bg2').mouseover(function(){
      $('body').css('background', '#880192')
   });
   $('#bg3').mouseover(function(){
      $('body').css('background', '#312431')
   });                
});
```

```css
.menuWrapper{
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    line-height: 1.45em;
    position:relative;
    margin:20px auto;
    height:542px;
    width:797px;
    background-position:0 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:transparent;
}
ul.menu{
    list-style:none;
    width:797px;
}
ul.menu > li{
    float:left;
    width:265px;
    height:542px;
    border-right:1px solid #777;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:transparent;
}
ul.menu > li.last{
    border:none;
}
.bg1{
    background-image: url(../images/1.jpg);
}
.bg2{
    background-image: url(../images/2.jpg);
}
.bg3{
    background-image: url(../images/3.jpg);
}
ul.menu > li > a{
    float:left;
    width:265px;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:450px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    color:#ddd;
    background-color:#333;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
ul.menu > li ul{
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    margin-top:-180px;
    width:100%;
    height:110px;
    padding-top:20px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:transparent;
}
ul.menu > li ul li{
    display:none;
}
ul.menu > li ul.sub1{
    background-image:url(../images/bg1sub.png);
}
ul.menu > li ul.sub2{
    background-image:url(../images/bg2sub.png);
}
ul.menu > li ul.sub3{
    background-image:url(../images/bg3sub.png);
}
ul.menu > li ul li a{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height:30px;
    margin-left:20px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #444;
    font-size:11px;
}
ul.menu > li ul.sub1 li{
    display:block;
}
ul.menu > li ul li a:hover{
    border-bottom:1px dotted #fff;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Template</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <style>
            *{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }
            body{
                font-family:Arial;
                padding-top:30px;
                background:rgba(102,148,163,1) url(title.png) no-repeat top center;
            }
            a.back{
                background:transparent url(back.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
                position:absolute;
                width:150px;
                height:27px;
                outline:none;
                top:2px;
                right:0px;
            }
            .reference{
                margin:20px auto;
                width:600px;
                padding:20px;
            }
            .reference p a{
                text-transform:uppercase;
                text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
                color:#666;
                text-decoration:none;
                font-size:10px;

            }
            .reference p a:hover{
                color:#333;
            }
        </style>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]>
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styleIE6.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">

            <div id="menuWrapper" class="menuWrapper bg1">
                <ul class="menu" id="menu">
                    <li class="bg1" style="background-position:0 0;">
                        <a id="bg1" href="#">Lorem</a>
                        <ul class="sub1" style="background-position:0 0;">
                            <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dolor</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sit</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="bg1" style="background-position:-266px 0px;">
                        <a id="bg2" href="#">Amet</a>
                        <ul class="sub2" style="background-position:-266px 0;">
                            <li><a href="#">Consetetur</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sadipscing</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Elitr</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="last bg1" style="background-position:-532px 0px;">
                        <a id="bg3" href="#">Shop&Voting</a>
                        <ul class="sub3" style="background-position:-266px 0;">
                            <li><a href="#">Vote-Shop</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Voting</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

          
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.bgpos.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#bg1').mouseover(function(){
                    $('body').css('background', '#361738')
                });
                $('#bg2').mouseover(function(){
                    $('body').css('background', '#880192')
                });
                $('#bg3').mouseover(function(){
                    $('body').css('background', '#312431')
                });                
            });
        </script>
        
        
        
        
  <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var current = 0;
    
    var loaded  = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i <4; ++i)
     $('<img />').load(function(){
      ++loaded;
      if(loaded == 3){
       $('#bg1,#bg2,#bg3').mouseover(function(e){
        
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.parent().index() == current)
         return;

        var item = e.target.id;

        if(item == 'bg1' || current == 2)
         $('#menu .sub'+parseInt(current+1)).stop().animate({
             backgroundPosition:"(-266px 0)"
         },
         300,
         function(){
          $(this).find('li').hide();
         });
         
        else
         $('#menu .sub'+parseInt(current+1)).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(266px 0)"},300,function(){
          $(this).find('li').hide();
         });

        if(item == 'bg1' || current == 2){
         $('#menu > li').animate({backgroundPosition:"(-800px 0)"},0).removeClass('bg1 bg2 bg3').addClass(item);
         move(1,item);
        }
        else{
         $('#menu > li').animate({backgroundPosition:"(800px 0)"},0).removeClass('bg1 bg2 bg3').addClass(item);
         move(0,item);
        }

        if(current == 2 && item == 'bg1'){
         $('#menu .sub'+parseInt(current)).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-266px 0)"},300);
        }
        if(current == 0 && item == 'bg3'){
         $('#menu .sub'+parseInt(current+2)).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(266px 0)"},300);
        }

        
        current = $this.parent().index();
        
        $('#menu .sub'+parseInt(current+1)).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"},300,function(){
         $(this).find('li').fadeIn();
        });
       });
      } 
     }).attr('src', '/images/'+i+'.jpg');
                function move(dir,item){
                    if(dir){
                        $('#bg1').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"},200);
                        $('#bg2').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-266px 0)"},300);
                        $('#bg3').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-532px 0)"},400,function(){
                            $('#menuWrapper').removeClass('bg1 bg2 bg3').addClass(item);
                        });
                    }
                    else{
                        $('#bg1').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"},400,function(){
                            $('#menuWrapper').removeClass('bg1 bg2 bg3').addClass(item);
                        });
                        $('#bg2').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-266px 0)"},300);
                        $('#bg3').parent().stop().animate({backgroundPosition:"(-532px 0)"},200);
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've got three div's with id's: bg1, bg2 and bg3.

The color don't care. I can change the background-colr without problems...
but HOW it change... I don't like. I want it to fade a little bit with fadeIn or Out.

But when I fade the 'Body' in or out the whole website fades with it.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this CSS to your stylesheet. It will give a fadeIn - fadeout kind of animation

```
body {
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: One question do I have...

Before changing the background color, my header was showed. But when I changed it, I can't see it anymore.
Any idea?

Comment: what do you mean by not integrated?

Comment: the code in the question was not everything of my page.

Comment: I saw your link, what is wrong? I can't seen to understand

Comment: When you enter the website and you do not hover the menu, you can see a Header named 'Buzzteria WoW'. But when you hover the menu - so you change the background - the header is away

Answer (score 0):

The pure jQuery does not have functionality to animate colors. You have to use [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com) or [jQuery color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color).

Then use `.animate()` function.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xsnge/33/)

Comment: you need to add `jquery-ui.js and jquery-ui.css`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is probably with css3 transitions:

```
body{
  /* Other Css */
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
  /* transition: property duration timing-function; */
}
```

Then every time you change the background-color of body it will animate the colors.